# How thick are date bins

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am trying to make a histogram of frequency of occurrences at certain dates and I would like each of my bins to represent a whole year.  I do not know what the bin width should be to make the bin the width of a year.  Right now I have:

```
Year <-
  data.frame(dat = sample(seq(
    as.Date("1987-01-01"), as.Date("2017-01-01"), by = "day"
  ), 1000), num = rnorm(2000))

ggplot(Year, aes(x = dat)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 365)
+ scale_x_date(seq(min(num) - 20, max(num))))
```

I chose 365 because I was hoping that the numbers would represent days.  Also My data is over 30 years and is in the correct format of (yyyy/mm/dd).

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, the numerical form of dates is in seconds. So in your example, you would want 365*24*60*60 for your binwidth to (roughly) be one year wide.

A better option would be to specify the `breaks` of the histogram. This ensures that your breaks are, for example, on Jan 1st at the start of each year, and correctly accounts for leap years, leap seconds, and other time/date shifts.

Assuming your date column is formatted `as.POSIXct`, try:

```
library(lubridate)

ggplot(Yeer, aes(x = dat)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks = as.numeric(unique(floor_date(Yeer$dat, "year"))))
```

Comment: Thank you.  My data was formatted as a.Date but I think the same should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some datetime formatting to achieve this.

```
as.numeric(format(date,"%Y"))
```

You can then change the `stat` on your plot to give you what you need.